# Key error with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am building a RESTful API with DjangoRestFrameowork and came across an error when trying to use `choices` in my model. When accessing the api endpoint, I get the error `KeyError at /jobs/  u'job_type'`. My model has

```
JOB_CHOICES = (
    ('p', 'Paint'),
    ('pw', 'Pressure Wash'),
    ('h', 'Hourly'),
)

class Job(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    budget = models.IntegerField()
    job_type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_CHOICES,
                                default='p',
                                max_length=100)
```

and my serializer looks like this:

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
      model = Job
      fields = ('pk',
              'budget',
              'created',
              'job_type',)
```

I can't figure out where this is going wrong. They do something very similar to this in the Django-Rest-Framework tutorial and I can't figure out what is different about mine. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the full error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  452.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  449.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
  241.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  47.         return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  618.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  213.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  568.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  435.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in to_representation
  1041.         return self.choice_strings_to_values[six.text_type(value)]

Exception Type: KeyError at /jobs/
Exception Value: u'job_type'
```

Comment: when does it happens? when you POST or GET?

Comment: When I GET, haven't tried POST yet

Comment: It looks like one of your objects has a `job_type` with a value of "job_type", which isn't a valid choice. There's a DRF ticket about it that's still open.

Comment: So you mean like this may be a bug? Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: @bencunningham You could test Kevin's theory by adding another element to your `JOB_CHOICES` of `('job_type', 'BAD DATA'),` and see if it comes up, and also look for that "BAD DATA" to find your bad record.

Comment: you may add the `job_type` as field with default value, that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Meta class should be an inner class of the serializer, not a separate class. Try this:

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('pk',
                  'budget',
                  'created',
                  'job_type',
        )
```

Comment: Oh sorry that is the formatting, the Meta class is an inner one